# How can I unregister an unused node type in jackrabbit

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I have a problem, jackrabbit throw an exception when I try to unregister a NodeType. That nodetype is not used by any Node.

The code:

```
NodeTypeManagerImpl ntMgr = (NodeTypeManagerImpl) session.getWorkspace
            ().getNodeTypeManager();
ntMgr.unregisterNodeType("qae:base");
```

The exception is:

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: The check for the existence of content using the given node type is not yet implemented, so to guarantee repository consistency the request to unregister the type is denied. Contributions to implement this feature would be welcome! To restore the broken behavior of previous Jackrabbit versions where this check was simply skipped, please set the disableCheckForReferencesInContentException system property to true.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:69)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:51)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:45)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.RepositoryServiceImpl.unregisterNodeTypes(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:2605)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.WorkspaceManager$1.unregisterNodeTypes(WorkspaceManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.NodeTypeCache.unregisterNodeTypes(NodeTypeCache.java:156)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.NodeTypeCache$1.unregisterNodeTypes(NodeTypeCache.java:182)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.NodeTypeRegistryImpl.unregisterNodeTypes(NodeTypeRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.NodeTypeManagerImpl.unregisterNodeTypes(NodeTypeManagerImpl.java:403)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.AbstractNodeTypeManager.unregisterNodeType(AbstractNodeTypeManager.java:125)
    at com.quiter.qae.test.TestUnstructured.setUp(TestUnstructured.java:55)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:228)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:223)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.OldTestClassRunner.run(OldTestClassRunner.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

There is a workarround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's what i do if there is no content stored for this node type.

```
Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
NodeTypeManagerImpl nodeTypeManager = (NodeTypeManagerImpl)workspace.getNodeTypeManager();      

NodeTypeRegistry.disableCheckForReferencesInContentException = true;
nodeTypeManager.unregisterNodeType("dms:FILE");
```

However, i don't know how to do NON-TRIVIAL node type modification nor deleting node type definition and then re-import.